# Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard + sound issues

Tags: 18.04, sound, keyboard, input-devices

I have a laptop with **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** installed.

Working properly for a while (random amount of time), the keyboard gets BLOCKED with no response to any key.

Also, this is accompanied by youtube video lagging (frames start to repeat themselves).

Everything else continues to work normally.

Thanks in advance.